# what is the proper way to use nested async await in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, asynchronous, async-await

I'm really confused about this, what I'm trying to do is that when Express receives data from the user, I need to iterate over the (orders) and request some data for each (order) from another server using Socket.IO then waiting for the data, and do it all over again.

**My Controller:**

```
exports.placeOrders = async (socket, orders) => {
    for await (order of orders){ 
        console.log("Order ID: " + order.id);   

        socket.emit('requestOrderDetails', order.id);

         await socket.on('getDetails' , async (response) => {

                 console.log("order details:" + response);

                //another processes that should be executed in order
                // await .. 
                // await ..


             })

        }
    console.log("Process Finished);
}
```

**Expected Behavior:**
Order ID:,
order details:,
Process Finished,

**What I'm getting:**
Order ID:,
Process Finished,
order details:,

I have tried **for** loop & **for await of**. But the same result.

Comment: Don't mix event driven coding with promise-driven coding.  You won't be able to control the flow or error propagation accurately.  If you're waiting for just one `getDetails` message, then you can promisify that using [`once()`](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_events_once_emitter_name_options) and then use only promises to control your flow.

Comment: @jfriend00 I tried to avoid this approach but I couldn't. Since requesting extra details from another server using sockets is asynchronous process, I'm trying to find an alternative flow.

Comment: Perhaps you're not understanding what I'm suggesting.  Promisify the socket event delivery so you can then use entirely promises to manage your operation.  I even pointed you to a library function that can do the promisify for you.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that’s what you’re trying to achieve

```js
exports.placeOrders = async (socket, orders) => {
  socket.on('requestOrderDetails' , async (response) => {

      console.log("order details:" + response);

      //another processes that should be executed in order
      // await .. 
      // await ..
  });

  for (let index = 0; index < orders.length; index++){ 
      console.log("Order ID: " + orders[index].id);   

      socket.emit('requestOrderDetails', orders[index].id);
  }
  
  console.log("Process Finished);
}
```

You dont need to create an event listener for each order, that listener will be executed always when the event name requestOrderDetails is emitted.

Comment: Not exactly, this server needs to request extra details from another server by using Sockets as I mentioned. requestOrderDetails should be emitted to the second server providing it the id of each order.